# How to make dropdown menu control <audio> tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```html
<audio id="playme" src="audio/music.mp3" loop autoplay>Your browser...</audio>

<img id="pic" src="pic/pic1.jpg" height="95%" />


<p>
<input type="button" style="font-size: 10px;"
    OnClick="document.getElementById('playme').src='audio/music.mp3';"
    value="Lavender">

<input type="button" style="font-size: 10px;"
    OnClick="document.getElementById('playme').src='audio/music2.mp3';"
    value="Dyskietkowe BHG :D">

<p>

<input type="button" style="font-size: 10px;"
    OnClick="document.getElementById('pic').src='pic/pic1.jpg';"
    value="pic1">

<input type="button" style="font-size: 10px;"
    OnClick="document.getElementById('pic').src='pic/pic2.jpg';"
    value="inen pic1">
```

I'd like to change these buttons into **two dropdown menus** (`<select>`),
but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is mate, working and stuff:

Edit: your post was edited to split in two lists, so here is the code:

```
<audio id="playme" src="audio/music.mp3" loop autoplay>Your browser...</audio>

    <img id="pic" src="pic/pic1.jpg" height="95%" />

    <select id="fldSelectA" style="font-size: 10px;" >
        <option value="Lavender">Lavender</option>
        <option value="Dyskietkowe">Dyskietkowe BHG :D</option>
    </select>

    <select id="fldSelectB" style="font-size: 10px;" >
        <option value="pic1">pic1</option>
        <option value="inen">inen pic1</option>
    </select>

    <!-- if you already have jquery in your page, remove this line-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#fldSelectA").change(function(){
        switch($(this).find("option:selected").val()){
            case "Lavender":
                document.getElementById('playme').src='audio/music.mp3';
                break;
            case "Dyskietkowe":
                document.getElementById('playme').src='audio/music2.mp3';
                break;
        }
    });

    $("#fldSelectB").change(function(){
        switch($(this).find("option:selected").val()){
            case "pic1":
                document.getElementById('pic').src='pic/pic1.jpg';
                break;
            case "inen":
                document.getElementById('pic').src='pic/pic2.jpg';
                break;
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Notice behaviour differences from `<button>` to `<select>`, and what I made to both work make the same task. Have a nice day and comment here if that is good for you or if you have any doubt.

Comment: Instead of `$(this).find("option:selected").val()` use simply `this.value`

Answer (score 0):

**Let's have some fun with JS** and let our *program* do all the stuff instead of us.
All we need is to set:

- images names and URL
- songs names and URL

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/AnuHEVU/1/edit)*

```
var multimedia = {
  "audio" : [
     ["Lavender",           "audio/music.mp3"    ],
     ["Dyskietkowe BHG :D", "audio/me_guitar.ogg"]
  ],
  "image" : [
     ["Pic1",     "pic/pic1.jpg"],
     ["Inen pic", "pic/pic2.jpg"]
   ]
};
```

What we need is a `DIV` container `#controllers` where jQuery will put our `<select>` elements, and an image with **ID** `#audio` and an `<audio>` element with **ID** `#audio`
<sub>Note the names similarity with the *multimedia* sections.</sub>

```
<div id="controllers"></div>
<img id="image" src="" />
<audio id="audio" src="" loop autoplay>
  Audio Not Supported
</audio>
```

and finally the magic:

```
for(var key in multimedia){ // 2 loops: audio, images
  if(multimedia.hasOwnProperty(key)){    

      // Create one Select element
      var newSelect = "<select name='"+ key +"'>",
          key = multimedia[key],
          keyN = key.length;
      // Fill it with Option elements
      for(var i=0; i<keyN; i++){ // loop separately (audios, images) contents
          newSelect += "<option value="+ key[i][1] +">"+ key[i][0] +"</option>"; 
      }
      newSelect += "</select>";
      // Append created select element
      $('#controllers').append( newSelect );

  }
}

$("#controllers").on('change', 'select', function(){
  $('#'+ this.name)[0].src = this.value;
}).find('select').trigger('change');
```